# How to connect between Indonesian Air Asia and Jetstar at Denpasar (Bali) airport?

Tags: transit, bali, lombok

We are looking into the following flight plan:

```
Air Asia QZ431 LOP-DPS arriving at 12:30
Jetstar 3K242 DPS-SIN departing at 14:25
```

This would give us roughly two hours between flights.

According to my research, both Air Asia and Jetstar use the international terminal at Denpasar (which is a bit surprising because the Air Asia flight is clearly a domestic connection).

[image: QZ431]
[image: 3K242]

Given that we are travelling with hand luggage only (so no need to claim bags) and check-in online, is this connection possible? Do we need to go through customs and immigration or check-in at the counter; or is our connection treated as transit and we only need to change gates? [Denpasar to Singapore is listed as a Straight to Gate flight for Jetstar.](https://www.jetstar.com/sg/en/help/articles/straight-to-gate-international-flights)

I know it's tight either way but if we don't need to exit and re-enter the only gamble should be that our first flight isn't delayed which we're willing to take. Is there anything else we're missing?

Does anyone have recent experience with such short transits in DPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done a similar transfer in the other direction recently. The Domestic and International wings of the airport are only a 10-min walk apart.  If you check in to *both* flights in advance, with electronic boarding passes, and have no bags, the connection will be straightforward.  However, DPS-SIN is an international flight, so you will need to clear Immigration at Denpasar, and depending on your nationality (in particular, if you need a visa for Singapore) Jetstar may require you to check in in person to show your documents.

My main concern with your plan is that Air Asia does not have a great on-time record, so you don't have a whole lot of buffer if they're delayed, and Jetstar will show you no mercy if they are.  A direct flight from Lombok to Singapore would be safer and much more convenient.